# Nested route member as a first class member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to make nested route actions act as a first-class member?

```
resources :links do
  resources :favorites
end
```

I would like to make actions of FavoritesController (favorite/unfavorite or create/destroy) act like first-class members of LinksController inside routes, e.g. /link/:id/unfavorite..
Would that be RESTful? Or should I put favorite/unfavorite actions right inside LinksController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like that:

```
resources :links do
   member do
     get :favorite
     get :unfavorite
   end
end
```

You must define favorite and unfavorite actions in your LinksController.

Comment: Even if I have Favorite model, would it be still best practice? Tho I did the way you have described it, I thought it might be cleaner to have separated controller and view folder for better maintenance. But I I disliked the URIs that time.

Comment: For me, it's more model code and not controller code. So your favorite method will look like: @link.favorite. All the code will be in the model. If you have commun code in different models, you can create a module (in the lib folder) and extend your model with this module!